# Como puedo usar una funcion vue en un controlador laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Tengo este boton el cual al hacer click manda a llamar una funcion de vue que se ejecuta sin problema, el detalle es que esa funcion (que es un mensaje de exito) se ejecuta siempre que se da click en el boton, pero si valido el formulario y no se envia con exito de todas formas ejecuta la funcion vue, como puedo hacer para que ejecute la funcion vue solo si el formulario se envia con exito?

HTML:

```
    @extends('layouts.amortizaciones')
@section('content')
    {{-- <div class="">
        @if (count($errors->all()))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>
                                    {{$error}}
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div> --}}
<div class="" id="editar_factura">
    <form class="needs-validation" action="" method="post" name="edita_amortizacion" novalidate>
        @csrf
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalProducto" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalProducto" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <div class="row col-md-12 text-center">
                                <div class="col-md-4">Efectivo</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body col-md-12 row center">
                            <div class="col-md">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control focus" name="cantidad" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Debe Ingresar una Cantidad
                          </div>
                            </div>
                            <br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            {{-- <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="vent">Pagar</a></td> --}}
                            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="coti2">Pagar</button> </td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" id="cancela_venta" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancelar</a></td>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- -->
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach ($am as $a)
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cliente" value="{{$a->nombre}}" class="form-control" disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label for="cliente">Factura</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nofac" value="{{$a->id_fac_enc}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="idcliente" value="{{$a->id_cliente}}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label for="nit">Nit</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nit" class="form-control" value="{{$a->nit}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label for="dir">Direccion</label>
                            <input type="text" name="dir" class="form-control" value="{{$a->direccion}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <td>Fecha</td>
                    <td>Cantidad</td>
                    <td>Saldo</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($am2 as $a2)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($a2->updated_at))}}</td>
                            <td>Q.{{$a2->cantidad}}</td>
                            <td>Q.{{$a2->saldo}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @foreach ($saldo as $sa)
                        <input type="hidden" name="saldo" value="{{$sa->saldo}}">
                    @endforeach
                    {{-- @foreach ($cot_det as $detalle)
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{$detalle->cantidad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$detalle->categoria}} {{$detalle->producto}} Marca {{$detalle->marca}}</td>
                    <td>Q{{$detalle->precio_venta}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach --}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row justify-content-between container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        {{-- <div><td>Q{{$detalle->total}}</td></div> --}}
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalProducto">Abonar</a>
    {{-- <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Regresar</a> --}}
    <a href="{{ action('AmortizacionController@index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Regresar</a>
</div>
</div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

estaba pensando en agregarlo en el controlador despues de la parte del ->save(); pero no se como meter codigo vue alli.

VUE:

```
coti2(){
      var resp=confirm("Esta seguro de realizar la Cotizacion?");
      if (resp==true)
      {
        toastr.success('Cotizacion Realizada con Exito', 'Trypode Systems', {
            "progressBar": true,
            "timeOut": "3000"
          });
        document.envia_cotizacion.action='/cotizaciones';
        // document.envia_cotizacion.submit();
      }
      else
      {
        alert("Cotizacion Cancelada");
        document.envia_cotizacion.method='HEAD';
        window.location="localhost:8000/cotizaciones";
      }
    }
```

Esto va a un FormRequest.

y en el controlador:

```
public function store(AmortizacionStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $amorti = new Amortizacion;
        $amorti->id_cliente = $request->input('idcliente');
        $amorti->id_fac_enc = $request->input('nofac');
        $amorti->cantidad = $request->input('cantidad');
        $amorti->saldo = $request->input('saldo')-$request->input('cantidad');
        $amorti->save();
        sleep(3);
        return redirect()->action('AmortizacionController@index');
    }
```

este es todo el codigo de esa parte del modulo

Comment: Vue se ejecuta en el cliente, no en el servidor. Lo que puedes hacer en el controlador es retornar un mensaje de éxito (con status 200 por ejemplo) o de error (status 500 por ej). Y en axios, ajax o lo que estés usando, mostrar un mensaje basado en la respuesta del servidor

Comment: Gracias, y como haría eso que me dices?

Comment: ok, veo que agregaste el html de un modal con un input y el botón donde se llama a la función `coti2()`, pero en la pregunta mencionas un formulario que no se ve donde está, como és, ni como se relaciona con el modal. Tampoco se ve como lo envías, ¿lo haces con esta línea que está comentada? `// document.envia_cotizacion.submit();`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es capturar el evento submit del formulario, y luego llamas la funcion que Creaste en Vue

```
<form id="form_envio" class="needs-validation" action="" method="post" name="edita_amortizacion" novalidate>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#form_envio").on("submit", function(e){
e.preventDefault();

app.coti2();
})


})
</script>
```

Estoy suponiendo que tu tienes una instancia de Vue llamada app

```
 var app = new Vue({
      el: 'app2',
      data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Eder, tenés que hacer en el cliente y laravel que solo tenga los métodos REST en este caso entonces los llamás así

```js
const addAsset = async addAsset({ name }) {
        const response = await Vue.http.post(
            `/assets`,
            {
                name,
               
            },
        );
        return response.data;
  };

addAssest({name: "pepito.jpg"})
```

Entonces así tendrás mejor armonía entre un framework de javascript que es del frontend y el Backend en este caso laravell solo hará la inserción y devolverá un json con la respuesta y el status tipo así

```js
return {
  status: 200,
  result: {name: "pepito"}
  error: false
 }
```

Y el Frontend pregunta por ese status para devolver o no errores:

```js
try {

  const result = await addAssest({name: "pepito.jpg"});
  if (result.status === 200) {
    const newAsset = result;
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("err:", e.error)
}
```

Avisame si tenés mas dudas te explico mas y hacemos un ejemplo en codesandbox.